# Why doesn't Stream.limit work as expected in this snippet?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
List<Integer> integer = Stream.generate(new Supplier<Integer>() {
    int i = 0 ;

    @Override
    public Integer get() {
        return ++i;
    }
}).filter(j -> j < 5)
  .limit(10)   // Note the call to limit here
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Counter to my expectation, the `collect` call never returns. Setting `limit` before `filter` produces the expected result. Why?

Comment: By the way you might use `Stream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1).filter(...)...` instead of this funky supplier.

Comment: @AlexisC. I was not aware of this API. Thanks!

Comment: Or better, IntStream.range().

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since there are only 4 elements that pass the filter, `limit(10)` never reaches 10 elements, so the Stream pipeline keeps generating new elements and feeding them to the filter, trying to reach 10 elements that pass the filter, but since only the first 4 elements pass the filter, the processing never ends (at least until `i` overflows).

The Stream pipeline is not smart enough to know that no more elements can pass the filter, so it keeps processing new elements.

Comment: "The `Stream` pipeline is not smart enough to know that no more elements can pass the filter"…and, indeed, [it can't be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Answer (score 25):

Flipping the `limit` and the `filter` clauses has different behaviors.

If you put the `limit` first, the stream will first generate 10 integers [1..10], and then filter them leaving only those smaller than 5.

In the original ordering, with the `filter` applied first, integers are generated and filtered until you reach 10 elements. This isn't an infinite operator, as `i` in the supplier will eventually overflow, but it will take a while, especially on a slow computer, to reach `MAX_INT`.

Comment: I didn't consider the eventual int overflow. +1

Comment: Maybe it’s about when the optimizer starts its work, but on my machine, the overflow and subsequent completion of the operation happens within less than a second…

Answer (score 18):

If you want to stop *either* if number 5 is reached or 10 elements are collected, there's `Stream.takeWhile()` method added in Java-9:

```
List<Integer> integer = Stream.generate(new Supplier<Integer>() {
    int i = 0 ;

    @Override
    public Integer get() {
        return ++i;
    }
}).takeWhile(j -> j < 5).limit(10).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 9):

It will finish, after the Supplier overflows and starts generating negative numbers. The resulting list will contain:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, -2147483648, -2147483647, -2147483646, -2147483645, -2147483644, -2147483643]
```

The reason for this is in other answers. On my i7 machine it took 40 seconds to complete.